# Getting cleaned HTML in text from HtmlCleaner

Tags: html-parsing, htmlcleaner

I want to see the cleaned HTML that we get from HTMLCleaner.
I see there is a method called serialize on TagNode, however don't know how to use it.
Does anybody have any sample code for it?

Thanks
Nayn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the sample code:

```
HtmlCleaner htmlCleaner = new HtmlCleaner();

TagNode root = htmlCleaner.clean(url);

HtmlCleaner.getInnerHtml(root);

String html = "<" + root.getName() + ">" + htmlCleaner.getInnerHtml(root) + "</" + root.getName() + ">";
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a subclass of `org.htmlcleaner.XmlSerializer`, for example:

```java
// get the element you want to serialize
HtmlCleaner cleaner     = new HtmlCleaner();
TagNode     rootTagNode = cleaner.clean(url);

// set up properties for the serializer (optional, see online docs)
CleanerProperties cleanerProperties = cleaner.getProperties();
cleanerProperties.setOmitXmlDeclaration(true);

// use the getAsString method on an XmlSerializer class
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new PrettyXmlSerializer(cleanerProperties);
String        html          = xmlSerializer.getAsString(rootTagNode);
```

Comment: Actually, this answer should be accepted answer. This method gives full HTML without manually injecting root node.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new PrettyXmlSerializer(cleanerProperties);

String html = xmlSerializer.getAsString(rootTagNode);
```

the method above has a problem,it will trim content in html label, for example,

> this is paragraph1.

```
 will become
```

> this is paragraph1.

and it is `getSingleLineOfChildren` function does the trim operation. So if we fetch data from website and want to keep the format like tuckunder.

PS:if a html label has children label,the parent label contetn will not be trimed,

for example `<p>   this is paragraph1. <a>www.xxxxx.com</a>  </p>`  will keep whitespace before "this is paragraph1"